# Shortkey for runnig or debugging one single unit test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

I have written a unit test. I want to run JUST that test the moment I finish coding. What is the visual studio and ReSharper shortcut to make things faster? How about if i want to debug the test?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for Running the single unit test ctrl + U,Y 
And for Debugging the single unit test ctrl + U,D worked ok for me.